# How to change Add to basket text on the storefront theme

Tags: woocommerce, storefront

I cannot seem to replace the text inside the Add to basket buttons on the single product pages, im using a child theme with the storefront theme for WooCommerce.

Here's what i've tried:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text');

function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text() {
   return __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce');
}
```

How the button appears on the DOM:

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="117" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to basket</button>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `storefront` theme? Because I am not finding the `Add to basket` test in theme anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think the issue is theme-related as your code does work when I try it on a test site, though I don't have Storefront set as the theme.

You could try a string replace:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_woocommerce_strings', 999, 3 );

function change_woocommerce_strings( $changed, $text, $domain ) {
$changed = str_ireplace( 'Add to basket', 'Add to cart', $changed );

return $changed;
}
```